# Change iframe target and close target div from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

See my code below, what I'm trying to achieve is that when a user clicks on 'Div 1' the menu slides open to choose Web 1, but when clicking that, the menu closes and the iframe changes.

Currently only either hiding the menu or changing the iframe works, but not both.

I have added a second 'Div 2' to show the changing of the iframe.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js" integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .targetDiv {
      display: none;
      background-color: red;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    .iframe {
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="targetDiv">
    <a href="http://www.skysports.com/" class="showSingle" target="myiframe">Web 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="targetDiv">
    <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target="myiframe">Web 2</a>
  </div>

  <iframe src="http://www.bing.com/" name="myiframe" class="iframe"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
      var index = $(this).parent().index(),
        newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index);
      jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast')
      newTarget.delay('fast').slideToggle('fast')
      return false;
    })
  });;
</script>
```

Comment: Although your question is unclear, a quick solution will be to add `class="showSingle"` to the `a` having text `Web2`, you forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe blocked your div, so I changed the style of it.

Your "a" tag should has the class "showSingle". After removing it, everything works.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(index);
    var newTarget = $('.targetDiv').eq(index);
    $('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').slideToggle('fast')
    return false;
  });
  $(".targetDiv a").click(function() {
    $('.targetDiv').slideUp('fast')
  });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50px;
}

.iframe {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js" integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="showSingle">Div 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="targetDiv">
  <a href="http://www.skysports.com/" target="myiframe">Web 1</a>
</div>
<div class="targetDiv">
  <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target="myiframe">Web 2</a>
</div>

<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/" name="myiframe" class="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I think you misunderstood. I want the red target div to remove when clicking on Web 1/Web 2.

Comment: I updated the answer. Just adding a click listener to the links. @JDCov87

Comment: Brilliant that works, thanks for your help @blackmiaool

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it. :) @JDCov87